# Shiny: access input object from own JS script

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

In Shiny `conditionalPanel` in `condition` arg it is possible to access JS `input` object, so in case of having for example `numericInput("num", label = h3("Numeric input"), value = 1)` widget, value of this widget is reachable in `condition` JS expression via `input.num`.

The question is how to access, in the same way, `input` object in own JS script (launched within Shiny app) or just from the browser's console opened on the Shiny app page?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best way is probably by listening for [`shiny:inputchanged` events](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/js-events.html).

```
library(shiny)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    tags$head(tags$script("
      $(document).on('shiny:inputchanged', function(event) {
        console.log(event);
        console.log('[input] ' + event.name + ': ' + event.value);
      });
    ")),
    numericInput("num", "", 0, 0, 5),
    textInput("txt", ""),
    actionButton("action", "Action")
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {}
)
```

You could also send input values back up from the server using [`session$sendCustomMessage`](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/session.html) and `Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler`.

---

An undocumented, much less recommended way would be to access the input values directly through `Shiny.shinyapp.$inputValues`, an object that stores values under `name:type` keys:

```
{
  "action:shiny.action": 4,
  "num:shiny.number": 2,
  "txt": "text"
}
```