# Access javascript objects from R in shiny dashboard

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

There are many shiny questions on SO asking how to use an input value in UI. The general answer is to use the `updateSelect`-family or to use `renderUI`.

I understand that it is basically not possible to access values from the input list (`input$...`) in the UI, since the input list is only passed to the server and therefore not existent in the UI environment.

What I do not get my head around is, that there are functions such as `conditionalPanel` which access the input list in javascript and use it to render UI output.

Since those functions actually use the input list in javascript, I wonder whether it is possible to build some shiny function (lets name it `js()`) which passes the javascript input list back to R and make it accessible in the UI.

It would make creating UIs much easier.

I tried to look deeper into the `conditionalPanel` function to better understand how the javascript environment is accessed, but the condition argument is passed to a `div()` attribute called `data-display-if`. From here on I don't know how to dig deeper into the function.

```
conditionalPanel <- function(condition, ..., ns = NS(NULL)) {    
  div(`data-display-if`=condition, `data-ns-prefix`=ns(""), ...)    
}
```

Finally I provide a code example of a functional shiny dashboard. I commented out two statements: one which will not work, and one with a fictional function `js()` that accesses a input value in javascript and passes it to R. It would be great to have such a function in the future.

```
library("shiny")
library("data.table")

# Generate data
testDT <- data.table(a1 = c(rep("group1",4),rep("group2",4),rep("group3",4)),
                     a2 = rep(c("red","blue","green"),4),
                     x1 = c(5,6,7,3,4,5,2,3,4,2,1,7),
                     x2 = c(1,2,3,2,3,2,1,4,6,7,3,4),
                     x3 = c(12,43,64,34,93,16,32,74,84,89,45,67)
)

shinyApp(

    ui = fluidPage( # user interface

        sidebarLayout( # layout with Sidebar

            sidebarPanel( # input sidebarPanel

                selectInput(inputId = "subset", label = "Choose group",
                            choices = c("Group 1" = "group1",
                                        "Group 2" = "group2",
                                        "Group 3" = "group3"),
                            selected = "group1"),

                conditionalPanel(
                    condition = "input.subset == 'group3'", # input value can be access in javascript
                    sliderInput(inputId = "range x3", label = "Choose range for x3",
                           min = 0,
                           max = max(testDT$x3),
                         # max = max(testDT[a1 == input$subset]$x3), not possible since input list not available in UI
                         # max = max(testDT[a1 == js('input.subset')]$x3), a function like js() would be great 
                           c(0,max(testDT$x3)),
                           step = 1))

            ), # closes sidebarPanel

            mainPanel( # Output in mainPabel

                tableOutput("table")



            ) # closes mainPanel

        ) # closes sidebarLayout

    ), # closes fluidPage

    server = function(input, output) {

        react_testDT <- reactive({

            testDT[a1 == input$subset,.(x1_mean = mean(x1),
                                        x2_mean = mean(x2),
                                        x3_mean = mean(x3))]

        })

        output$table <- renderTable({

            react_testDT()

        })

    }

)
```

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/blob/5c03326a8c7c1f202b55b2bb99cdf4f592fd2f17/inst/www/shared/shiny.js#L12219) they are searching for div's with the `data-display-if` attribute checking the given conditions and modify the `display` CSS properties. However, I'm not sure how this can be applied in another context. Listening on shiny [JS events](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/js-events.html) is [another approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47733984/shiny-access-input-object-from-own-js-script/47734398#47734398).