# Load or read the data dynamically using the output of selectinput in Ui.R

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

In my `ui.R` I use the following `selectInput` to read the data in server.R

```
selectInput(inputId = 'date',
          label = 'Stichtag:',
          choices = list.files('./data', full.names = FALSE,
                   recursive = FALSE)),
```

is there any possibility to read the data in ui.R directly in order to use it for further `selectInput`:

```
data<-fread(paste0('./data/',input$date))
```

please take into account I know how one can read it in **server.R**. The question is, how can I do it directly in `ui.R`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pass the read data in server.R into ui.R using shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57093296/pass-the-read-data-in-server-r-into-ui-r-using-shiny)

Comment: @BigDataScientist :) possibly but not exact. You can probably use for the other one updateSelectInput

Comment: Can you read the data in with code in `global.R`? It's implicit to [scoping rules in shiny](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/scoping.html), and available to both the UI and server elements. (This is assuming that the data is known before the UI/UX are started.)

Comment: @r2evans: the problem is, depending on the selection in 'selectInput' I should read another data set.

Comment: Perhaps I don't understand ... I would definitely lean towards `updateSelectInput` in an `observe` or `observeEvent` (looking at the code in the other question).

Comment: Somehow related to my yet unanswered question which asks on a deeper level how to access input values in JavaScript to use them in UI: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57096471/access-javascript-objects-from-r-in-shiny-dashboard